# R How to trace overall shape of multiple plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a plot of multiple objects over time and I want to draw a single line to trace the dominant shape of the time-series. Currently the code I used for the plot is:

```
a$id = rownames(a)
am = melt(a, id='id')
ggplot(am)+geom_line(aes(x=variable, y=value, group=id, color=id))
```

Please can you help me to add a line that traces the overall shape of the curve? I'm not quite sure how to do it myself. Thank you.

Comment: Give `?geom_smooth` a look.

Comment: @hrbrmstr hi I have just tried adding `+ geom_smooth(aes(x=variable, y=value))` to my `ggplot` code but it doesn't produce any line!!?? a little more help please...

Comment: To re-iterate @jd8585's non-answer posit, how do you expect/plan to summarize/combine the series to then use `geom_smooth`?

Comment: @hrbrmstr umm… sorry I don't understand?? how should I use `geom_smooth` please I simply want to draw a line along the dominant shape of the curve thats all

Comment: @maryam And how do you estimate the dominant shape? With a mean, a percentile, something else?

Comment: @Pascal median maybe? whatever gives the more accurate shape works for me really!!

Comment: See http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_smooth.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what kind of summary statistics you are looking for. But regardless, `?stat_summary` is a good place to start. Below are some reproducible data and two possible summary statistics.

```
# create reproducible example
set.seed(123)
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
a <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(400), 20))
a[, 5] <- a[, 5] + 2
a[, 15] <- a[, 15] + 2
a$id = rownames(a)
am = melt(a, id='id')
p <- ggplot(am, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=id)) + geom_line(aes(group=id))
# plotting median
p + stat_summary(mapping=aes(group=1), 
                 fun.data=function(x) data.frame(y=median(x)), 
                 size=1.3, 
                 color='black',
                 geom="line")
# mean and ci's
p + stat_summary(mapping=aes(group=1), 
                 fun.data='mean_cl_normal', 
                 size=1.3, 
                 color='black',
                 geom="smooth")
```

Comment: OMG shadow this is amazing you're awesome!!! thank you so so sooo much you just saved my life!!! thank you!!!